# Find shell script and rename row

Tags: bash, shell, sed, find

I have shell script with name script.sh. I need to find this script and change value inside script

From:

```
bash $current_dir/run.sh
```

to

```
./run.sh.x
```

my solution is something like:

```
find -maxdepth 10 -name "script.sh" -exec sed -i 's#bash '$current_dir'#run.sh#.#runs.sh.x#' {} \ ;
```

But still my command does not work. Any idea how to replace this string in new string in my shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sed` expression seems to be the issue.

You can use:

```
find . -maxdepth 10 -name "script.sh" -exec sed -i 's#bash \$current_dir/run\.sh#./run.sh.x#' {} +
```

Comment: Thank you for very fast reply. I have an error - sed: can't read s#bash \$current_dir/run\.sh#./run.sh.x#: No such file or directory :-(

Comment: @Paul, if you have GNU sed, remove the `''` -- this appears to have been written to be correct for MacOS/BSD sed.

Comment: @Paul, ...the `-i` argument to `sed` isn't POSIX-standardized, so different implementations handle it different ways; one of those differences is what bit us here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yeah thank you for positive comment. I just deleted quotes ' ' and right now it seems ok to me. Once again thank you both guys.

Comment: @Paul: Indeed Charles was right, it was tested on OSX. I've removed extra `''` from `sed` command.

Answer (score 1):

@anubhava is correct. Another sed command which you can use.

```
find . -maxdepth 10 -name "script.sh" -type f | xargs -I {} sed -i 's/.*\/run.sh/\.\/run.sh.x/g' {}
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your inputs. I placed the file inside directory which contains spaces and it still works and holds good. AFAIK, `-I` will be able handle spaces also.

Comment: Actually, you're right. Directories with literal newlines are still a problem, but behavior with `-I {}` is not incorrect with spaces.

Comment: That said, to demonstrate the bug from using `xargs` without `-0` with newlines in filesnames: `mkdir -p $'dir\nwith\nnewlines' && touch $'dir\nwith\nnewlines/script.sh'; find . -name script.sh | xargs -I {} printf '<%s>\n' {}`; the output is `<dir>`, `<with>`, `<newlines/script.sh>`.

Comment: ...compared to correct behavior: `mkdir -p $'dir\nwith\nnewlines' && touch $'dir\nwith\nnewlines/script.sh'; find . -name script.sh -exec printf '<%s>\n' {} +`; in that case the output is (correctly) `<dir`, `with`, `newlines/script.sh>`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have placed the folder `test hello` inside `/home/pnallathambi/learn/shell` and ran `find . -name "ls.sh" -type f | xargs -I {} sed -i 's/.*\/run.sh/\.\/run.sh.x/g' {}` from `/home/pnallathambi/learn/`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks anyway. I will investigate on your point. But am sorry, it still works!

Comment: I don't deny that it works in the common case, I'm only pointing out that it introduces some extra bugs (even if they're only encountered under very unusual circumstances), when it would be possible to write code that didn't have them. Odd corner cases are the stuff of security bugs -- think of someone making a malicious file with `mkdir -p $'./tmp/\n/etc/passwd\n' && touch $'./tmp\n/etc/passwd\n/script.sh`, tricking your code into modifying `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to sidestep `sed` compatibility issues is to rely on `perl`. Adopting an answer from [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021):

```
search='bash $current_dir/run.sh'
replace='./run.sh.x'
in="$search" out="$replace" find . -name script.sh -exec \
  perl -pi -e 's/\Q$ENV{"in"}/$ENV{"out"}/g' '{}' +
```